# Fast Fourier Transformation using parallel processing coding for image processing

Tags: fft, image-processing, c

I'm now working in parallel precessing -and i want a full code for fast Fourier transform(FFT)
written  parallel processing Code for any image processing application

Comment: As the close text says, we don't answer questions here that sound like they're asking for code written to a specification. If you have specific *signal processing* questions about what you're trying to do, please edit the question and we may be able to keep this question open.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should have a look at [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/) as their implementation allows you to use more than one thread to perform the FFT. One thing that should note with this library is that multi-threading is not necessarly beneficial for all problems sizes as stated [here](http://www.fftw.org/doc/How-Many-Threads-to-Use_003f.html#How-Many-Threads-to-Use_003f). For a software application that I'm working on, for example, using multiple threads slows down things (the biggest FFT being on 4096 points).